# Git post-receive nor post-update hooks aren't executed

Tags: git, devops, githooks

- I use these hooks on my git server (another computer from my local network).
- Yes, files are executable.
- Yes, partition, where git repo is situated, doesn't have an noexec flag.
- Yes, I'm sure that I push new files and my server have something to update.
- Yes, script body code works properly.
- Yes, my files are named properly.

[image: hook files name]

My system - server - Ubuntu, connection to the git server via HTTPS

Comment: Please show the code or [mcve]. Explain why do you think the hooks were not executed. Did you try to add some debugging output?

Comment: Have you done something like add a simple echo to stdout/stderr from the hook as a very first command, to see if they are executed at all?